# Saving ServletHttpRequests (Java)

Tags: java, http, servlets, httprequest

Is there anyway to save a `HttpRequest` in Java? Basically I have a scheduling servlet and what I want to do is save the `post` request and give it to the job to allow them to decide what to do with it.

Comment: from request what do you read from servlet?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that pulling out only the pieces you need into a custom object would be best.  If you want all of the request parameters you could always grab the entire contents of the parameter map using `getParameterMap()`. That way you can not carry around any unneeded fields and be able to save using any storage technique you want.